# Add a second action or a link to a Laravel Notification

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-notification

I am sending a notification using Laravel and am having trouble figuring out how to send a second action.  Here is my code for the `toMail` method:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject($this->options['subject'])
        ->greeting($this->options['greeting'])
        ->line($this->options['contentParagraph1'])
        ->line($this->options['contentParagraph2'])
        ->action('Facebook', 'https://www.facebook.com/')
        ->line($this->options['contentParagraph5'])
        ->action('LinkedIn', 'https://www.linkedin.com/')
        ->line($this->options['contentParagraph3'])
        ->line($this->options['contentParagraph4'])
        ->salutation($this->options['salutation']);
}
```

What I am getting, is only the second action. It looks like the second action is overriding the first one. Is there a way to keep both actions or to use a link instead of a button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `SimpleMessage` class is designed for creating simple messages that have one call to action button, you can find the code that powers the functionality in [Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/SimpleMessage.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/SimpleMessage.php#L191) and the template for the SimpleMessage emails can be found in [Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Notifications/resources/views/email.blade.php) — note the single button.

You can create more complex messages using the [Markdown Mail Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#markdown-mail-notifications) feature, which will allow you to include as many buttons as you like. You can implement this like so:

1. Run the command to generate a new notification and pass in the `markdown` option, e.g: `php artisan make:notification InvoicePaid --markdown=mail.invoice.paid`
2. Open the newly created template, e.g: `views/mail/invoice/paid.blade.php`
3. Add as many buttons as you like, e.g:

   ```
   @component('mail::message')
     # Introduction

     @component('mail::button', ['url' => $url1])
     Button 1 Text
     @endcomponent

     @component('mail::button', ['url' => $url2])
     Button 2 Text
     @endcomponent

     @component('mail::button', ['url' => $url3])
     Button 3 Text
     @endcomponent

     Thanks,<br>
     {{ config('app.name') }}
   @endcomponent
   ```
4. Replace your calls to `SimpleMessage` methods with a reference to your markdown template when constructing your email, e.g:

   ```
   return (new MailMessage)
     ->subject($this->options['subject'])
     ->markdown('mail.invoice.paid', $this->options);
   ```

The second parameter in the `markdown` method is an array to pass into your view, through this you can include the various values you'd like to include in your email, such as `contentParagraph1`, `greeting` and `salutation`.

Answer (score 4):

I implemented this workaround for adding a button to a standard `SimpleMail` object. Since `MailMessage::line()` can accept any object that implements `Htmlable`, you can put anything you want in it.

You still have to override the notification class to instead create an instance of `MyMultiButtonVerifyEmail` (instead of `VerifyEmail`), but that's easily done (and something you probably already had to do once updated email copy was provided).

Grrr, these default Laravel notification classes are not really reusable, are they?

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Action;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class MyMultiButtonVerifyEmail extends VerifyEmail {

    public function toMail($notifiable) {
        $verificationUrl = ...;
        $resendUrl = ...;

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('some line')
            ->action(Lang::getFromJson('Verify Email Address'), $verificationUrl)
            ->line('another line')
            ->line($this->makeActionIntoLine(new Action(Lang::getFromJson('Request New Activation'), $resendUrl)))
            ->line(Lang::getFromJson('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
    } // end toMail()

    private function makeActionIntoLine(Action $action): Htmlable {
        return new class($action) implements Htmlable {
            private $action;

            public function __construct(Action $action) {
                $this->action = $action;
            } // end __construct()

            public function toHtml() {
                return $this->strip($this->table());
            } // end toHtml()

            private function table() {
                return sprintf(
                    '<table class="action">
                        <tr>
                        <td align="center">%s</td>
                    </tr></table>
                ', $this->btn());
            } // end table()

            private function btn() {
                return sprintf(
                    '<a
                        href="%s"
                        class="button button-primary"
                        target="_blank"
                        style="font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, \'Segoe UI\', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, \'Apple Color Emoji\', \'Segoe UI Emoji\', \'Segoe UI Symbol\'; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 3px; box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16); color: #fff; display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; background-color: #3490dc; border-top: 10px solid #3490dc; border-right: 18px solid #3490dc; border-bottom: 10px solid #3490dc; border-left: 18px solid #3490dc;"
                    >%s</a>',
                    htmlspecialchars($this->action->url),
                    htmlspecialchars($this->action->text)
                );
            } // end btn()

            private function strip($text) {
                return str_replace("\n", ' ', $text);
            } // end strip()

        };
    } // end makeActionIntoLine()

}
```

For posterity, this was written for Laravel 5.8.32. There may be better ways of accomplishing this in later versions of the framework. YMMV.